# Tweepy: How to post a new status with hashtags?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

So I was able to post a pure text status update using

```
api.update_status("You're awesome! ")
```

But how do you add a hashtag towards the status?

Specifically,

api.update_status("You're awesome! #sf ") will post everything but the hashtag.

Comment: Try it with the entity reference for #.